# схожесть действий стандартных алгоритмов is_partitioned и all_of

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Никак не смог понять чем отличаются эти два алгоритма.

```
string s = "(double) k / 12";
auto pred = [](char c) { return c == '/'; };    
bool b1 = is_partitioned(s.begin(), s.end(), pred);
bool b2 = all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), pred);
cout << boolalpha << b1 << endl /*false*/ << b2; /*false */
```

Читал как они реализованы, но не нашел разницу. И чем же отличаются эти два алгоритма, кто поможет разобраться?
Добавление к вопросу:

Для того, чтобы я лучше понял,  прошу на моем примере добавить символы  или поменять предикат так, чтоб  результат двух алгоритмов был разным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all_off` вовращает `true` если **все** элементы диапазона при проверке `pred` выдают `true`. Т.е. ни один элемент при проверке не даст `false`.

`is_partitioned` возвращает `true` если все элементы диапазона, которые при проверке выдают `true` находятся перед элементами, которые при проверке выдают `false`. Т.е. некоторые элементы могут при проверке давать `false`, но должны находиться после элементов, которые дают `true`:

`[true, true, true, true, false, false]` будет true.

`[true, true, false, true, false, false]` будет false, потому что после первого false еще есть true (или, что то же самое, до последнего true встречается как минимум один false).

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в ответе  Эникейщик последный пример  [true, true, false, true, false, false]  будет false. не поясняет суть, но в остальном ответ правильный и я смог разобраться. Вот пример:

```
string s = "double d = 34";
auto pred = [](char c) { return !isdigit(c); };

bool b1 = is_partitioned(s.begin(), s.end(), pred);
bool b2 = all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), pred);
cout <<boolalpha << b1 <<endl;
//результат true, поскольку  строка разделена на нечисла и числа
cout << b2; // false поскольку в строке есть и числа
```

Так что, спасибо Эникейщику!..